# how to extract first tag from json object in python

Tags: python

I have some json data similar to this...

```
{
    "company": "abc",
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "john",
            "age": "24"
             ...
             ...
        },
        {
            "name": "peter",
            "age": "32"
             ...
             ...
        },
        ...
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to have `"company": "abc"` in one variable and
then `key = json.dumps({k: data[x] for x in people})`

I have tried something like this:

```
for k in item['people']:
        print k['name'], k['value']
```

How do I extract company from json response before iterating list.

Output as :

Output as

"company": "abc",
{
"name": "john",
"age": "24"
...
...
}
"company": "abc",
{
"name": "peter",
"age": "32"
...
...
}

Comment: how do you want your output?

Comment: Output as : 

"company": "abc",
    {
            "name": "john",
            "age": "24"
             ...
             ...
    }
"company": "abc",
    {
           "name": "peter",
            "age": "32"
             ...
             ...
    }

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
results = []
for p in json_data['people']:
    data = [{'company': json_data['company']}, p]
    results.append(data)
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[
    [{"company": "abc"}, {"name": "john", "age": "24" ... ... }],
    [{"company": "abc"}, {"name": "peter", "age": "32" ... ... }],
]
```

Comment: Thank you this helps. However, I cannot hard-code 'people' and 'company: abc'. this is an example.  Will get response from json and it it starts with some header text (ex: company: abc) followed by List<items> then I need to display-  "header text": { "": "", "": "" ... ... }

Comment: is they key `company` always fixed?

Comment: Nope, it not fixed. It will come thorugh API

Comment: can you show another example

Comment: ;y bad,key is constant value would change

Comment: I have updated the solution, kindly check

Comment: Got it. This really helped me as I am beginner in python. Thank you